# doctrine querybuilder limit and offset

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

i'm a symfony beginner and i want to make a blog with the framework. i use repository to get home articles with this method :

```
public function getHomeArticles($offset = null, $limit = null)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
               ->leftJoin('a.comments', 'c')
               ->addSelect('c')
               ->addOrderBy('a.created', 'DESC');


    if (false === is_null($offset))
        $qb->setFirstResult($offset);

    if (false === is_null($limit))
        $qb->setMaxResults($limit);

    return $qb->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
}
```

so in my database i have 10 articles. In my BlogController i use :

```
$blog = $em->getRepository('TestBlogBundle:Article')
                ->getHomeArticles(3,4);
```

With this i want 4 articles. But in return i also have one article.

What is the problem?

Comment: Well, everything looks fine except "addSelect('c')" try to remove this line of code. Also make sure that there are really 10 or more comments in the database. Oh, well, this [url]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701792/doctrine2-limiting-with-left-joins-pagination-best-practice[/url] article might help.

Comment: thank's Vadim. i have 10 articles ( and 20 comments). i try to remove addSelect but it's not work. i don't understand why this code is not working...

Answer (score 47):

This is a [know issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/doctrine-user/BGH9a8zFFn0) where `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()` need to be use with care if your query contains a fetch-joined collection.

As stated about [First and Max Result Items](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only):

> If your query contains a fetch-joined collection specifying the result
>   limit methods are not working as you would expect. Set Max Results
>   restricts the number of database result rows, however in the case of
>   fetch-joined collections one root entity might appear in many rows,
>   effectively hydrating less than the specified number of results.

Instead, you can:

1. Lazy load
2. use [the Paginator](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html#pagination) (as stated by @Marco here)
3. Use [`Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection::slice()`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/v1.0/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Collection.php#L231-L242)